# Returning Serialized JSON Data from an Array

Tags: c#, json.net

I am currently creating a class library for an API. Here is my current issue:

The API has support for multi-call functionality in which I can get data for multiple submissions (i.e. a Skin, Model, Script, etc.) all at the same time in the form of an array holding an object for each of the submissions. The link I will be providing is completely for testing purposes as it returns the same submission three times and can be found [here](http://api.gamebanana.com/Core/Item/Data?&itemtype[]=Model&itemtype[]=Model&itemtype[]=Model&itemid[]=3962&itemid[]=3962&itemid[]=3962&fields[]=animated,apps_used,authors,catid,contestid,creator,cumulative_rating,date,description,Downloadable().bFileExists(),Downloadable().nGetFilesize(),Downloadable().sFileUrl(),downloads,feedback_instructions,file,Flags().aGetActiveFlagRowIds(),Flags().nGetActiveFlagsCount(),lastpost_date,lastpost_userid,mapped,mdate,modnote,name,polycount,postcount,Posts().Postcount().nGetPostCount(),rating,screenshots,Stats().nGetNewestSubmissionId(),Stats().nGetSubmissionCount(),studioid,text,textured,Trash().bIsTrashed(),tricount,userid,views,votes,Withhold().bIsWithheld()&fields[]=animated,apps_used,authors,catid,contestid,creator,cumulative_rating,date,description,Downloadable().bFileExists(),Downloadable().nGetFilesize(),Downloadable().sFileUrl(),downloads,feedback_instructions,file,Flags().aGetActiveFlagRowIds(),Flags().nGetActiveFlagsCount(),lastpost_date,lastpost_userid,mapped,mdate,modnote,name,polycount,postcount,Posts().Postcount().nGetPostCount(),rating,screenshots,Stats().nGetNewestSubmissionId(),Stats().nGetSubmissionCount(),studioid,text,textured,Trash().bIsTrashed(),tricount,userid,views,votes,Withhold().bIsWithheld()&fields[]=animated,apps_used,authors,catid,contestid,creator,cumulative_rating,date,description,Downloadable().bFileExists(),Downloadable().nGetFilesize(),Downloadable().sFileUrl(),downloads,feedback_instructions,file,Flags().aGetActiveFlagRowIds(),Flags().nGetActiveFlagsCount(),lastpost_date,lastpost_userid,mapped,mdate,modnote,name,polycount,postcount,Posts().Postcount().nGetPostCount(),rating,screenshots,Stats().nGetNewestSubmissionId(),Stats().nGetSubmissionCount(),studioid,text,textured,Trash().bIsTrashed(),tricount,userid,views,votes,Withhold().bIsWithheld()&return_object=1).

The goal is to grab the raw JSON data for each object and put it into a string array so that I can go through each of the objects and deserialize them individually. The reason for this is that the api could return any kind of object (as specified above) and this system must adjust to each object that goes through it. Here's the current code:

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static WebClient web = new WebClient();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        APICaller ApiManager = new APICaller(web);

        Model exampleObject = new Model(3962);
        Model exampleObject2 = new Model(3962);
        Model exampleObject3 = new Model(3962);

        List<Model> SubmissionInstances = new List<Model>() { exampleObject, exampleObject2, exampleObject3 };
        int[] IDs = new int[] { exampleObject.itemID, exampleObject2.itemID, exampleObject3.itemID };
        string[] fields = new string[] { exampleObject.fields, exampleObject2.fields, exampleObject3.fields };

        ApiManager.Data(SubmissionInstances, IDs, fields);
    }
}
```

APICaller.cs

```
        public List<object> Data<T>(List<T> type, int[] itemid, string[] fields)
    {
        //Same as the first function but supports multi-call
        string itemTypes = "";
        string itemIDs = "";
        string itemFields = "";
        string finalURL = "http://api.gamebanana.com/Core/Item/Data?";

        int i = 0;
        foreach (object obj in type)
        {
            itemTypes += "&itemtype[]=" + obj.GetType().Name;
            types[i] = obj.GetType();
            i++;
        }
        foreach (int ID in itemid)
        {
            itemIDs += "&itemid[]=" + ID;
        }
        foreach (string field in fields)
        {
            itemFields += "&fields[]=" + field;
        }
        finalURL += itemTypes + itemIDs + itemFields + "&return_object=1";

        string[] JSONObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(client.DownloadString(finalURL));
        List<object> toReturn = new List<object>();

        i = 0;
        foreach (string str in JSONObjects)
        {
            toReturn.Add(DeserializeObject(type[i], str));
            i++;
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    public T DeserializeObject<T> (T obj, dynamic JSONObj)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JSONObj);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: From [ask]: *Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.*  You haven't done that so we can't really help you.

Comment: The question is how to do I grab the raw json for each object using JSON.Net